# Сложение чисел в php

Tags: php

В файле записаны числа `111000.5-2`.

Нужно, чтобы файл *php* посчитал числа, и получилось `1.5`.

Как сделать так, чтобы *php*[файл считал `0.5` как `0.5` а не `0` и `5`? Может, заключить в скобки?

Еще я не знаю, как посчитать `-2`.

Вот что пока получилось с ваших советов

```
<?php
$content = "1 1 1 0 0 0.5 -2";
$somecontent = explode(" ", $content);
print_r($somecontent);
$result = count($somecontent);
echo $result;
?>
```

Но это выдает 7 почему-то, наверное считает кол-во цифр.
Код, который у меня был:

```
 $file = file_get_contents('test.txt')
 $file = ИвановИванИвановичСпиридоновЕщенко1111001
 preg_match_all("/[А-Я][а-я]+/", $file, $names);
 preg_match_all("/\d{1}/", $file, $numbers); 
 foreach($numbers[0] as $num) {
     $sum = $sum + $num; //складываем
}
$data = $names[0][0].' '.$names[0][1].' '.$names[0][2].', '.$names[0]   [3].', '.$names[0][4].', '.$eks[0][5].', '.$sum;
```

А дальше шла запись в другой файл. Может сюда можно приписать что-то, чтобы считало дробные и отрицательные? Сделать так, чтобы изначально в файле были пробелы не проблема

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно использовать какой-то разделитель для чисел в файле. Думаю, что стоит сначала определиться с форматом.

Comment: Ок, а если числа будут записаны в формате 1 1 1 0 0 0.5 -2 ?

Comment: Если пробел - разделитель, то вам нужно прочитать строку, разбить ее по разделителю и просуммировать элементы получившегося списка.

Comment: По поводу формата, а не проще ли массив данных перегонять в json и сохранять в файл? А потом когда нужно - json_decode().... ну или serialize/unserialize...

Comment: @alexeich json не нужен если есть внятный разделитель.

Comment: @AlexSpiridonov, а что вы уже пробовали делать? Или вопрос сводится к "_напишите код за меня_"?

Comment: У меня был уже готовый код на вариант без дробных и отрицтельных чисел, но, он их считает неправильно, обратился сюда. Вот что пока получается по вашим советам : <?php
$content = "1 1 1 0 0 0.5 -2";
$somecontent = explode(" ", $content);
print_r($somecontent);
$result = count($somecontent);
echo $result;
?>

Comment: Но, получается почему-то 7

Comment: Вот что было в оригинале: $file = file_get_contents('test.txt'); preg_match_all("/[А-Я][а-я]+/", $file, $names); 
preg_match_all("/\d{1}/", $file, $numbers);   foreach($numbers[0] as $num) {
    $sum = $sum + $num; //складываем
}

//собираем данные
$data = $names[0][0].' '.$names[0][1].' '.$names[0][2].', '.$names[0][3].', '.$names[0][4].', '.$names[0][5].', '.$sum;  и дальше идет запись в файл

Comment: @AlexSpiridonov, Пожалуйста, перенесите этот код в вопрос, дополнительно указав пример чисел в формате с пробелом. Это поможет вам получить ответ быстрее.

Comment: хочу напомнить что php не всегда корректно складывает дробные числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нечетком случае, когда число фамилий и чисел может варьироваться, придётся полагаться на регулярные выражения. Для получения чисел, я бы взял регулярное выражение для цифр 0-9, точки и знака минус: `[0-9\.-]`. Для имён – всё, кроме цифр, точки, пробела и знака минус: `[^0-9\.\ -]`.

Сложить все элементы массива можно без цикла встроенной ф-ей [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php). А перечислить массив имён через пробелы – ф-ей [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) или её синонимом `join()`:

```
// $file = file_get_contents('test.txt')
$file = "Иванов Иван Иванович Спиридонов Ещенко 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0.5 -2";

preg_match_all("/[^0-9\.\ -]+/", $file, $names);
preg_match_all("/[0-9\.-]+/", $file, $numbers);

$data = implode(' ', $names[0]) . ' ' . array_sum($numbers[0]);
// Иванов Иван Иванович Спиридонов Ещенко 3.5
```

Если известно, что всегда ровно пять имен и девять чисел, можно использовать форматированный ввод [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sscanf.php):

```
$row = sscanf( $file, '%s %s %s %s %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f'); 
$data = implode(' ', array_slice($row, 0, 5)) 
    .' '
    . array_sum( array_slice( $row, 5, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Получить файл как ресурс
2. Разбить файл по переносу строки например explode()
3. Первое число получаем [floatval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floatval.php), остальные регулярками.
4. Все это кладем структурировано в массив.
5. Далее [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) перебираем и выполняем ариф. действия.
6. На выходе массив с нужными значениями.

Comment: А причем тут перенос строки в п.2? А регулярные выражения в п.3?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я предполагаю что файл с данными содержит не одно выражение/значение "в файле записаны числа 111000.5-2". Регулярные выражения чтобы получить знак ариф. действия и последнее число.

Comment: Почитайте комментарии к вопросу. Под `111000.5-2` автор имеет в виду `1 1 1 0 0 0.5 -2`.

Comment: Изначально был вариант без пробелов, но даже если есть пробелы никто не запрещает использовать `str_replace(" ","",$str);` тогда когда это нужно...

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что `10 12 -2` -- это не тоже самое, что и `1 0 1 2 -2`? А `str_replace(" ","",$str);` даст идентичные результаты

Comment: Я может не понимаю, но по моему мнению слева одно число потом ариф. действие потом еще число. И непонятно почему данные в таком виде и откуда они приходят, почему нельзя использовать JSON или XML на крайний случай.

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить, что числа в файл записаны одной строкой и разделены пробелом, то можно попробовать так:

```
$file = file_get_contents('test.txt'); // Например, '1 2 10 12.4 -5 6'
$values = explode(' ', $file);
$sum = 0;

foreach($values as $val) {
    $sum += floatval($val);
}

echo($sum);
```